# Host keyboard not working when I remote desktop into the computer it's connected to

Tags: windows, keyboard, remote-desktop

I have the following setup:

- "Remote" computer: Intel NUC in a lab (no connected display)

  - OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Keyboard connected to the "remote" computer
- I remote desktop (RDP) into the remote computer
- I want to use both the keyboard on my laptop and the keyboard connected to the remote computer

Is there any way to make this happen?

I would prefer to change settings in the remote computer.

Comment: That's kinda by design - your remote computer will get locked when you remote in. Is using another protocol an option?

Comment: What other protocols would be a viable option?  I would prefer RDP, but am open to others.  Also, thank you @JourneymanGeek for responding